# What does vertical bar "|" (pipe) in function arguments type annotations mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, type-annotation

I came across function with signature like this:

```
def get_quantile(numbers: List[float], q: float | int ) -> float | int | None :
```

What does it mean?

It's a syntax error on my python 3.8. Do I need to import something from `future` to make it work?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/), `|` will be used to designate union types from Python 3.10.

So `float | int` will mean `Union[float, int]`, i.e. a float or an int.

Answer (score 3):

It means `or`. So `q: float | int` means that `q` may either be a `float` or an `int`.

Comment: Are you sure `or` can be in an annotation? Apart from some wierd calculations of types and values. Sorry for attacking your answer, but you made "or" look like a Python keyword which might mislead somebody ;)

Comment: It doesn't really mean `or`, but more properly "union", which is consistent with the usage of this same operator for sets and dictionaries. And no, the `or` keyword can't be used in the type annotation.