# What does | mean in a type annotation?

Tags: python

I am doing the fastai course for deep learning. I am confused with the initialization of DataLoaders class. Here is the code:

```
class DataLoaders(GetAttr):
    "Basic wrapper around several `DataLoader`s."
    _default='train'
    def __init__(self,
        *loaders,          # `DataLoader` objects to wrap
        path:str|Path='.', # Path to store export objects
        device=None        # Device to put `DataLoaders`
    ):
        self.loaders,self.path = list(loaders),Path(path)
        if device is not None or hasattr(loaders[0],'to'):    
               self.device = device
```

My question is: in the path argument, what does str|Path means?

Comment: More exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615988/what-does-vertical-bar-pipe-in-function-arguments-type-annotations-mean

Comment: Yeah, I picked the wrong duplicate too quickly.